# Javascript not linking when uploaded to server

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i view my site on my computer it looks fine, but once i have uploaded it to the server the Javascript is not linking. My console shows 403 forbidden errors on the four script src's.
The web address is http://fergalomahony.com/
Here are the four script src's that are getting the error.
Any advice on this would be much appreciated.

```
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sounds like a webserver configuration problem (haven't/wont click on your link). Is the webserver configured to return js files with the correct mimetype?

Comment: I'd take a wild stab in the dark that you may need to change the access permissions on the js directory and/or the four js files within it.

Comment: You should check your error.log and vhost configuration. If you open http://fergalomahony.com/js/jquery.min.js in your browser you see an additional 404 has been occured. There is something wrong in your server configuration.

Comment: this js file is working: http://fergalomahony.com/galleria-1.3.5.min.js so probably you just have to place the other .js files at the same place and then remove the "js/" from src="js/... and give read permission for everyone to those files but try first Billy suggestion (sorry havent seen that before)

Comment: Ah brilliant folks, thanks. I had changed the permissions on all the folders but not the files within the js folder. appreciate the help.